# Splitting a column in dataframe using str.split function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

I am trying to split a column with comma delimited values into 2 columns but the str.split function returns columns with 0's and 1's instead of the split string values

I have a dataframe with a column 'Full Name' which has a full name with a comma separating last name from first name.

I used the str.split function which works when I execute it for display only.  But: when I try to use the same function to add 2 new columns to the same dataframe with the split data, I get 2 new columns with the first populated with 0's and the second with 1's all the way.

The code that works to display the split data:

`df2015_2019.iloc[:,0].str.split(',', expand=True)`

Code that doesn't work to create new columns with split data:

`df2015_2019['Lname'],df2015_2019['Fname'] =  df2015_2019.iloc[:,0].str.split(',', expand=True)`

I get a column 'Lname' with all 0's and a column 'Fname' with all 1's

Comment: please review and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way around to achieve this as follows..

### Example DatatSet:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Karn,Kumar', 'John,Jimlory']})
>>> df
           Name
0    Karn,Kumar
1  John,Jimlory
```

### Result:

You can assign the column name while splitting the values as below.

```
>>> df[['First Name','Last Name']] = df['Name'].str.split(",", expand=True)
>>> df
           Name First Name Last Name
0    Karn,Kumar       Karn     Kumar
1  John,Jimlory       John   Jimlory
```

Or, as another answer stated..

```
>>> df['Name'].str.split(",", expand=True).rename({0: 'First_Name', 1: 'Second_Name'}, axis=1)
  First_Name Second_Name
0       Karn       Kumar
1       John     Jimlory
```

OR

```
>>> df['Name'].str.rsplit(",", expand=True).rename(columns={0:'Fist_Name', 1:'Last_Name'})
  Fist_Name Last_Name
0      Karn     Kumar
1      John   Jimlory
```

*Note: you can use `axis = columns` or `axis =1` both are same.*

Just another way using  **[`Series.str.partition`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.partition.html)**   with little altercation, However, we have to use `drop` as `partition` preserves the comma "," as well as a column.

```
>>> df['Name'].str.partition(",", True).rename(columns={0:'Fist_Name', 2:'Last_Name'}).drop(columns =[1])
  Fist_Name Last_Name
0      Karn     Kumar
1      John   Jimlory
```

Just make it slim, we can define dict values for the `rename`.

1 - using `str.partition` ..

```
dict = {0: 'First_Name', 2: 'Second_Name'}

df = df['Name'].str.partition(",", True).rename(dict2,axis=1).drop(columns =[1])
print(df)

  First_Name Second_Name
0       Karn       Kumar
1       John     Jimlory
```

2 - using `str.split()` ..

```
dict = {0: 'First_Name', 1: 'Second_Name'}

df = df['Name'].str.split(",", expand=True).rename(dict, axis=1)
 print(df)
  First_Name Second_Name
0       Karn       Kumar
1       John     Jimlory
```

Comment: what if the number of strings as name and second name are not consistent? such as  Karn Jon Kumar Jimlory is one full-name, and Jim  is the second name? I am asking this because I have a data that has inconsistent number of name and last name combinations.and I want to create columns by expanding 2-3..4... whatever. if there is no value, it shall be nan. that's OK :)

Answer (score 3):

You can rename the column after the split:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a,b', 'c,d']})
df['a'].str.split(',', expand=True).rename({0: 'Lname', 1: 'Fname'}, axis='columns')
```

This prints:

```
  Lname Fname
0     a     b
1     c     d
```

Answer (score 3):

The `pandas.Series.str` accessor can be assigned to the columns.

1. `split` first (optionally, use `n=1`) to keep exactly **one** split.
2. use another `str`

---

```
df['Lname'], df['Fname'] = df['Name'].str.split(',').str
```

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware you could do this. +1